# Почему дальше программа выкидывает исключение?

Tags: c#-8.0

Есть метод на проверку какого либо символа в числе

```
 public static int CheckNamber(ref int a, string txt)
 {        
    while (true)
    {
         Console.Write($"Введите {txt}: ");
             
         string text = Console.ReadLine();
         if (int.TryParse(text, out a))
         {
             a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             return a;  
         }
         else
         Console.WriteLine("Не удалось распознать число, попробуйте еще раз.");            
    }
   
 }
```

Должно возвращать число

Вызываю этот метод в другом классе

```
 Console.WriteLine("Найти самую большую цифру целого числа\n");         
     int a = 0, digit, max = 0;
     Program.CheckNamber(ref a, "целое число");
// здесь выдаёт исключение System.FormatException: "The input string '' was not in a correct format."
     while (a > 0)
     {
         digit = a % 10;
         if (digit > max)
         {
             max = digit;
         }
         a /= 10;
     }           
     Console.WriteLine($"Самая большая цифра числа = {max} ");
```

Почему он дальше с полученным числом не работает ?

Comment: Ваш метод `CheckNamber` запрашивает у пользователя ввод два раза (два вызова ReadLine) — я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что это действительно то, что вы хотели

Comment: @andreymal, а действительно . Спасибо я как то не обратил на это внимание;

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет правильно

```
public static int CheckNamber(ref int a, string txt)
{        
   while (true)
   {
        Console.Write($"Введите {txt}: ");

        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(text, out a))                          
            return a;              
        else
        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось распознать число, попробуйте еще раз.");            
   }      
}
```

Comment: в чем смысл делать одновременно и ref параметр и возврат значения, если они одно и тоже возвращают?

Comment: @Grundy, без ref так выводит 0, а с ref  он дальше работает с введённым числом

Comment: @Кирилл если вы полагаетесь на ref, то зачем тогда return?

Comment: @andreymal, ну а без return нечего не выводит, он постоянно повторяет ввод и все. А мне надо число введённое получить и с ним дальше работать

Comment: @Кирилл но вас никто не заставляет возвращать значение в return, можно сделать return без значения или вообще break. Такое чувство, будто вы плохо понимаете основы C#

Comment: @andreymal, да нет, судя по всему вы что то да забыли. В методе перед типом данных указан int, значит обязательно должен присутствовать return.  Если написать просто break, он число не изменит, изменит только у себя внутри метода и все. Если же  return a, то он вернёт переменную её значение. При этом в параметре должен стоять out  или ref  в данном случаи.

Comment: @Кирилл 1) «перед типом данных указан int» — и таки что вам мешает исправить int на void?; 2) «он число не изменит» — это неправда, прекрасно изменит именно потому что стоит `ref`

Comment: @andreymal, 1)void пишется в тех случаях когда параметры не указываются в методе, а так как метод имеет параметры то нельзя писать void.  2) Ну так я ref и написал , поэтому и изменил. А вы вообще предлогали не писать ref  , и   в место return break;  При все этом так корректно работать метод не будет. Сами та хоть проверьте что советуете ;)

Comment: @Кирилл 1) «так как метод имеет параметры то нельзя писать void» — это чушь, такого запрета нет; 2) «вы вообще предлогали не писать ref» — это тоже чушь, я такого не предлагал; 3) «Сами та хоть проверьте что советуете» — разумеется я проверяю всё что я пишу, и у меня всё отлично работает, а вы похоже запутали сами себя из-за слабого понимания основ C#

Comment: Короче, вот вам два варианта метода (проверенных и рабочих) — один без ref, другой без return https://onlinegdb.com/fzkqdrlZw